# Preserve All Original Settings when Launching Specific Firefox Profile via Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've successfully been able to launch a specific Firefox Profile in `Selenium WebDriver` using:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(dir);


FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
```

While I am able to launch a specific Firefox Profile using the above code, the issue I am facing is that not all settings are preserved. For example, I set the home page button to link to Google.com in the original Profile but when it is launched with the above code the home button doesn't do anything.

How can I preserve all settings related to the original profile when launching profile via selenium `WebDriver`?

Thanks